# Graphical issues in Ubuntu 14.10 with 3rd Gen Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Tags: 14.10, lenovo, thinkpad

I'm experiencing weird graphical problems with a fresh Ubuntu 14.10 install (see attached screenshots).

The laptop is a new Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon (3rd Gen) with 14" WQHD+ (2560 x 1440). External monitor is Dell UltraSharp 27" (also running 2560 x 1440) (U2713HM) connected using DisplayPort to Mini-DisplayPort.

Any idea what the issue could be? The distortions are not always present but appear after a while.

Screenshots:
[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I've been running this for about a day in Ubuntu, several hours, and haven't seen this problem yet. I have the non-touch 2560x1440 res screen. I'm curious if this only impacts certain screens or if the problem has been solved since this question was asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved this by switching from SNA to UXA.

Add */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf*, enter the following:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

More info here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Tips_and_tricks